# Launch iOS simulator from Visual Studio with Xamarian

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform

How can I launch an iOS simulator from Visual Studio? I'm working on Windows but have Visual Studio connected to my mac so I can develop a cross platform app.

I can successfully launch the iOS app to the iPad that is plugged into the Mac but can't figure out how to launch a simulator (I just want to test everything is loading good on different screens). 
When I set my `Solution Platform` to `iPhoneSimulator` and my `startup project` to `myApp.iOS` and click start I get the error message... `Please select a valid device before running the application.`

Comment: I would recommend keeping your question specific to one topic and not bring other off-topic questions in as well.

Did you select a valid iOS Simulator via the drop down which should list iOS Simulator devices?

Comment: Ok I will edit. And, when I select iPhoneSimulator from the drop down it doesn't give me any device list. Just `start` where the device list should be

Comment: You should see a similar dialog to this: http://screencast.com/t/mXZpzTbxcA74

If you do not, I would recommend pasting the `Xamarin` and `Debug` output from your output window

Comment: There isn't any output. Instead of that drop down list you linked to, all there is is the word `Start`. When I click that a dialog box appears saying to pick a valid device

Comment: I'd recommend following this troubleshooting article: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/ If you're still unsuccessful, post the respective logs into the question. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting/#Log_Data

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac open a terminal and enter:
ps -eax Xamarin
Get the pid of the IDB.exe process 
Kill it:
Kill 123456 
(Replace 123456 with the pid)
Wait a few seconds, vs drop down should fill.

Up vote if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem after I'd just installed the iOS simulator for Windows VS; restarted VS and the networked Mac and the drop-down filled.